# Mass removal of content and properties from divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a huge grid of divs that randomly generates content and background images and I want to create a function that will generate it again randomly, but before that it will obviously clear all text content and background images.

I tried doing it with:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("isq").innerHTML = null;
```

Also tried with textContent = "", nothing helped. I was also unable to use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("isq").style.backgroundImage = "none";
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is my html(just 1/4 of it, but it's basically the same:

```
    <div class="row r1">
    <div class="square o1">
        <div class="isq i1"></div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square o2">
        <div class="isq i1"></div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square o3">
        <div class="isq i1"></div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If it's somehow crucial for me to show how I generated the content and background for the divs let me know and I will simpilfy the JS code to show it but I dont think its necessary

Comment: What errors do you get and what do you try to solve them? I would expect `document.getElementsByClassName("isq")` to return an array, not a dom element, so you cannot access `innerHTML` like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `document.getElementsByClassName("isq")` is an array, you should do the following:

```
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("isq");

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    arr[i].innerHTML = null;
```

Comment: Use `forEach` for sake of simplicity

Comment: Okay, thank you, didn't know that it would require looping, I really need to study DOM more it seems

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("isq")` returns  `HTMLCollection` not array.

Answer (score 2):

From `document.getElementsByClassName('isq')` get an array and iterate through it and set the `innerHTML` to `''`.

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('isq');

var emptyDivs = function(){
  Array.from(divs).forEach(function(ele){
    ele.innerHTML = '';
  });
}

emptyDivs();
```

```html
<div class="row r1">
    <div class="square o1">
        <div class="isq i1">adsfas</div>
        <div class="isq i2">adfasd</div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square o2">
        <div class="isq i1">adfasdf</div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square o3">
        <div class="isq i1"></div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So loop is unavoidable, but at least I don't need a nested loop it seems. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, you won't need nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementByID(elementId).innerHTML = "";
```

For a class:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("someClass").innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Not sure why it was downvoted. This is the solution, but needs a loop over elements

Comment: I've got no single element with ID though. And even if I had i would need to create nested loop for that. I'm looking for a simple solution. I don't get why mine doesnt work.

Comment: Not sure either. Please up vote it and mark it as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is not complete though, please update it to a workable piece of code